Could a post-nuptial agreement be devised where both partners parental inheritance is excluded from being considered marital assets?
Imagine two people from very wealthy families getting married. They get pressured into getting married outside the communion of goods from their parents. Both partners are not unhappy with the what is yours is ours marriage setup.
Can a compromise be found where they agree that money inherited from parents can be deposited outside the communal bank account and will not be considered marital property in case of divorce.
What would be the case of such a post-nuptial agreement surviving divorce proceedings?

A related question would be whether the parents can structure the inheritance so as to achieve this effect, perhaps via some sort of trust.

canada
I have tagged this Canada, despite property division rules being provincial, because in every provincial and territorial jurisdiction in Canada, inheritances received by one spouse are not part of the divisible family property upon separation.

It is my understanding, having just gone through updating our will in light of having adult children now, that this holds in most if not all US jurisdictions as well.
